# How to avoid created date column to overwrite when data updated

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

```
Date createddate = new Date();
project.setCreateddate(createddate);
projectservice.savaorupdate(project);
```

In the above code  'createddate' column is saved ...
When I edit the bean and then it comes to a different controller I enter the modified date

```
    Date modifydate= new Date();
    project.setModifieddate(modifydate);
    projectservice.savaorupdate(project);
```

In this process the createddate column ll not get the value and its nullified.
Please give any solution to this situation.

Comment: When doing an update, you should retrieve the "project" from database first, and then set the values on it.

Comment: I am using Spring forms - so when i use model attribute in the "/edit_save.htm" controller I get al the values of project bean except the modified date(obviously) .. so i record it as mentioned above ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the hibernate Query is firing an update on unmodified columns also . Set the show-sql=true to find this .

```
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
```

You may set dynamic-update=true at the  tag level to sort it out . Check the link [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class) .

```
<class
    name="ClassName"                              (1)
    table="tableName"                             (2)
    dynamic-update="true|false"                   (8)
    dynamic-insert="true|false"                   (9)
/>
```

Comment: Aravind thanks for the answer where should I use <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>.... in applicationcontext.xml ?

Comment: To mention I use Hibernate with annotations

Comment: @Meenakshi I guess you use AnnotationSessionFactoryBean , if so , under your applicationcontext.xml  , you'll find the  property <property name="hibernateProperties"> , put it under that .

Comment: @ aravind .. I have my applicationcontext.xml as below                           
  <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">30</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

Comment: @Meenakshi - Now the queries should show up in the console as you execute them . Check out what's happening . If it's firing an update on all columns(I think it should be) - use dynamic-update="true" in your hbm at class level and try .